# How to set portrait orientation to particular one file using cordova?

Tags: cordova

I am working with cordova, I have created no of page. I am going to prevent landscape orientation for some file not for all file. How to set this method in cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look at this plugin?
https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

Usage

set to either landscape

> screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

allow user rotate

> screen.unlockOrientation();

access current orientation

> console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);

Kr